# Pass NULL parameter to SQL stored procedure using ADODB Connection object from Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I know it is possible to call a SQL Server stored procedure and populate a recordset in Access VBA by using the sp like a method on an ADODB Connection object:

```
Dim cnnTest As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsTest As New ADODB.Recordset

cnnTest.ConnectionString = strMyConnectionString
cnn.Open
cnn.procMyTestProcedure param1, param2, rsTest
```

This will call stored procedure `procMyTestProcedure` passing prarmeters `param1` and `param2`, returning the results to my local `rsTest` recordset. This all works fine and I have been using this technique for years. I have now come across a situation where I need to be able to pass a NULL as one of the parameters, but nothing I have tried so far seems to work. I have tried passing an empty string, the value Null and a local variable of type variant set to Null. None of these has worked. Does anyone know how to do this please? The parameter in the stored procedure is of type `smalldatetime`.

Comment: is your variable nullable in your proc? Regardless, a hack is this line of code right after your `as` in your proc to pass in a blank string but in the proc use it as a null `if @param='' set @param = NULL`. So basically passing in a blank string will turn into a NULL inside the proc.

Comment: Yes, I did think about doing that. I would have to redefine the parameter in the stored proc as string 'coz I can't pass an empty string to a datetime parameter. This would then have implications for validating a non-empty string before casting it as datetime. I just wondered if there was a 'proper' way of passing the null and avoiding the hassle of using a string instead. If not then I might go the long way round and use a Command object with defined Parameter objects (which can be set to Null).

Comment: Ah i see what you mean about the datetime parameter. I'm not sure about how to do it because I don't use ADO but perhaps this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1747641/6167855

Comment: Yes, that's going the Command.Execute route, explicitly declaring Parameter objects. I may end up doing this, but I prefer the more compact Connection.{proc_name} route. Just looks like this might not support passing Null parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `null` in VBA. It doesn't matter what data type you're using.

i.e.

```
    Dim parm1 As ADODB.Parameter
    Set parm1 = New ADODB.Parameter
    parm1.Direction = adParamInput
    parm1.Name = "StatisticsDate"
    parm1.Type = adVarChar
    parm1.Size = 50
    If IsEmpty(wsCell) Then
        parm1.Value = Null   'there is no DBNull - sorry
    Else
        parm1.Value = CDec(wsCell)
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this, but it fails with `Compile error: Variable not defined` and highlights `dbnull`

Comment: @Skippy I've updated the answer. For datetime I use 0 but that is translated inside a function in sql, which makes it the "default" date in sql - 31/12/1899 12:00:00. If you need datetime logic, I'll update the answer.