# Inserting NULL values in a database from VBA code

Tags: vba, adodb

I have 3 radioButtons ("YES", "NO", "UNKNOWN") which matches a column from my database with 3 possible values (1, 0, NULL).

When the radioButton selected is "UNKNOWN" I want to insert a NULL value in this table (using Variant type). But when I try to run my SQL query with my ADODB connection, it returns an error.

Is there a trick to pass NULL values in my database ? Here's a copy of my code :

```
Public Function setCandidature(idC As Integer, idO As Integer, nomC As String, prenomC As String, nomM As String, prenomM As String, idRegion As Integer, idUM As Integer, idDUM As Integer, nni As String, emploiC As String, repM As Integer, repA As Integer, accDisp As Integer, precAcc1 As Integer, precAcc2 As Integer)
Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim repAVar As Variant, repMVar As Variant

Set connect = New ADODB.Connection
connect.Open connString

If repA = -1 Then
    repAVar = Null
Else
    repAVar = repA
End If

If repM = -1 Then
    repMVar = Null
Else
    repMVar = repM
End If

sqlQuery = "UPDATE candidatures SET offre_ID = " & idO & ", candidat_Nom = " & nomC & ", candidat_Prenom = " & prenomC & ", manager_Nom = " & nomM & ", manager_Prenom = " & prenomM & ", reponse_Manager = " & repMVar & ", reponse_Agent = " & repAVar & ", region_Candidat = " & idRegion & _
           ", um_Candidat = " & idUM & ", dum_Candidat = " & idDUM & ", nni_Candidat = " & nni & ", emploi_Candidat = " & emploiC & ", accompagnement_Dispense = " & accDisp & ", accompagnement_Precision_ID = " & precAcc1 & ", accompagnement2_Precision_ID = " & precAcc2 & _
           " WHERE candidature_ID = " & idC & ";"
           
rs.Open sqlQuery, connect
End Function
```

I first pass the values that I want to be NULL as Integers containing -1.

Comment: Can you try `vbNull `?

Comment: @Vityata Like this ? :     repAVar = vbNull

Comment: Cause it does not work

Comment: Yup, thats what I thought. Try then like `repAVar = "Null"`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1747641/1188513

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is for your SQL statement to ultimately look like this:

```sql
UPDATE candidatures 
SET offre_ID = 42
   ,candidat_Nom = 'Doe'
   ,candidat_Prenom = 'John'
   ,manager_Nom = 'Nuts'
   ,manager_Prenom = 'Doug'
   ,reponse_Manager = NULL
   ,reponse_Agent = NULL
   ,region_Candidat = 'WEST'
   ,um_Candidat = 72
   ,dum_Candidat = 72
   ,nni_Candidat = 24
   ,emploi_Candidat = 'something'
   ,accompagnement_Dispense = 'whatever'
   ,accompagnement_Precision_ID = 10
   ,accompagnement2_Precision_ID = 11
WHERE candidature_ID = 2345;
```

You want strings to be enclosed in single quotes, numerical values to *not* be enclosed in such single quotes, and `NULL` values specified literally.

You could keep your string-concatenation approach, and make the query contain `NULL` values by concatenating `"NULL"` string literals into your query:

```vb
If repA = -1 Then
    repAVar = "NULL"
Else
    repAVar = repA
End If

If repM = -1 Then
    repMVar = "NULL"
Else
    repMVar = repM
End If
```

Obviously this means dealing with when/whether to include the single quotes, and when *not* to.

And that might work... until it doesn't:

```sql
UPDATE candidatures 
SET offre_ID = 42
   ,candidat_Nom = 'O'Connor'
   ,candidat_Prenom = 'David'
...
```

I know! I'll simply double-up any single quote in my string values! And that *might* work:

```sql
UPDATE candidatures 
SET offre_ID = 42
   ,candidat_Nom = 'O''Connor'
   ,candidat_Prenom = 'David'
...
```

But go down that hill and you're in for a ride... you'll keep patching up and "sanitizing" the user's input until things work again, then they break down, and you patch it again...

There's a *sane* way to do this.

Use parameters, and let the server deal with the parameters.

So instead of concatenating the parameter values into the command string, you send this to the server:

```sql
UPDATE candidatures 
SET offre_ID = ?
   ,candidat_Nom = ?
   ,candidat_Prenom = ?
   ,manager_Nom = ?
   ,manager_Prenom = ?
   ,reponse_Manager = ?
   ,reponse_Agent = ?
   ,region_Candidat = ?
   ,um_Candidat = ?
   ,dum_Candidat = ?
   ,nni_Candidat = ?
   ,emploi_Candidat = ?
   ,accompagnement_Dispense = ?
   ,accompagnement_Precision_ID = ?
   ,accompagnement2_Precision_ID = ?
WHERE candidature_ID = ?;
```

..along with *parameters*.

You don't work with a `Recordset`. You work with a `Command` instead:

```
Dim connect As ADODB.Connection
Set connect = New ADODB.Connection
connect.ConnectionString = connString
connect.Open

With New ADODB.Command
    .ActiveConnection = connect
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sqlQuery

    'append parameters in the same order they show up in the query
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adInteger, Direction:=adParamInput, Value:=myValue)

    '...
    .Execute
End With
connect.Close
```

To give the parameter a `NULL` value, simply use the `Null` keyword:

```
myValue = Null
```

This requires your nullable values to have a `Variant` data type, because an `Integer` or `Boolean` can't be `Null` in VBA.

Comment: I know the feeling when you write a giant answer, post it and see that someone has commented the essence of it! :)

Comment: @Vityata meh.. I wasn't going to make an answer that recommends concatenating `"Null"` into the command string - but I knew it was going to come up one way or another. The only sane way to do this is to use a parameterized command... and that's nowhere in the comments ;-)

Comment: Good `Command` example. :)  Perhaps you can write a VBA Wiki?

Comment: Well, leave some place for SQL injections, some people make a living out of it ;)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answers ! I haven't tried to make it work yet but would you recommend to use the ADODB.Command for every non-SELECT queries ? Also thanks for the tip on how to display my queries : it surely makes my code easier to read !

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am getting an error on the `.Execute` : "This parameter type is not handled" (poor translation but you get the idea), do I need an extra line to end the Parameters.Append ? If so, which method allows this ?

Comment: @NattyRoots I use `ADODB.Command` for everything *including* `SELECT` queries, parameterized or not. That way securely adding a parameter afterwards is a trivial change. Not sure what error you're getting, but make sure you use the appropriate types and that the parameters are appended in the same order as their respective placeholder `?` in the command text. `Append` is a method of `Command.Parameters`, the `.CreateParameter` function returns a `Parameter` object that `Append` uses; not sure what you mean with "to end the Parameters.Append".

Comment: I'd suggest you google up the *exact error message*, and then ask a separate question with it if you don't already find an answer on this site.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon is it possible to do this with `QueryTable` instead of `ADODB` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675562 ?

Comment: @NattyRoots Apropos SQL injection, see the section on ActiveX Data Objects at [bobby-tables.com](https://bobby-tables.com/com_automation).

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp adVariant is not supported by ADODB. But the following code worked for me to insert NULL into MariaDB: `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarChar, Direction:=adParamInput, Size:=1, Value:=Null)` It is critical to set the Size parameter to larger than 0.

Comment: @sdittmar not sure where you read anything involving adVariant in this answer. The last part is about the VBA data types to hold the data on the VBA side of things; a VBA string or integer can't be Null, you need a Variant to hold a Null value in VBA *on the client side*. Server side couldn't care less what data type the client variables are.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea for the future - whenever you are having a problem with big SQL code like this:

`sqlQuery = "UPDATE candidatures SET offre_ID = " & idO & ", candidat_Nom = " & more and more more SQL here";"`

Do the following:

1. Write 
   `debug.print sqlQuery` after the code.
2. Take the result from the immediate window and inspect it.
3. Copy it and take it into Access query. It should work. If it does not - inspect and debug further.

Edit: If you have the `time` & the `knowledge` & the `will to write good code`, do not write code like this. You may suffer from `SQL injection` and other problems. Instead use the method from the answer of Mat's Mug.

Comment: Arguably "whenever you are having a problem with big SQL code like this `sqlQuery = "SOME huge SQL statement WITH = " & concatenations & " AND " & moreConcatenations & ";"` ...solution is to get rid of the concatenations. But yeah +1 for showing how to use the debugger & immediate pane to fix things.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Getting rid of concatenations is exactly the way to do it, cannot agree more.