# Inserting Multilple Fields into SQL Server 2014 with an Excel VBA UserForm?

Tags: sql-server, vba

Can anyone show me how to multiple fields using with an inputbox using this method?

I would like to be able to insert a persons Name, Height, Gender, and Salary using a single UserForm?  So far I only know how to insert one field at a time like in the code below.

```
Dim SQL as ADODB.Command
Set SQL = NEW ADODB.Command
SQL.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [myStuff].[dbo].[myThings](Salary) VALUES    (?)"
SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Name",adNumeric,adParamInput,"Length of input here", MyInputBox.Value) ' Perhaps you have to validate MyInputBox.Value
SQL.ActiveConnection = CN
SQL.Execute
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522802/1188513) actually explains things.

Answer (score 4):

You could concatenate it into the query, but that in most cases it is a bad idea. Here is a parameterised version (see below). Note that you have to open a connection that are suitable for writing and possibly validate input of your `InputBox.Value`.

```vb
Dim SQL as ADODB.Command
Set SQL = NEW ADODB.Command
    SQL.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [myStuff].[dbo].[myThings](Salary) VALUES (?)"
    SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Name",adNumeric,adParamInput,"Length of input here", MyInputBox.Value) ' Perhaps you have to validate MyInputBox.Value
    SQL.ActiveConnection = CN
    SQL.Execute
```

Edit:
Here is a wrapper function that I use to simplify parameterising (you need to create and `ADODB.Command` object):

```vb
Function APCP( _
    ByRef Command As ADODB.Command, _
    ByVal DTE As DataTypeEnum, _
    ByVal PDE As ParameterDirectionEnum, _
    ByVal Value As Variant)
'APCP stand for "Append Parameter Create Parameter"
With Command
    Dim I As Long
    I = .Parameters.Count
    If Len(Value) > 0 Then
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f" & I, DTE, PDE, Len(Value), Value)
    Else
        Select Case DTE
        Case adNumeric
            Value = 0
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f" & I, DTE, PDE, 1, Value)
        Case adDate
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f" & I, DTE, PDE, 1, Null)
        Case Else
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f" & I, DTE, PDE, 1, vbNullString)
        End Select
    End If
End With
End Function

'Use Cases:
APCP YourADODBCommandObject, AdNumeric,adParamInput, 100
APCP YourADODBCommandObject, AdBoolean,adParamInput, True
APCP YourADODBCommandObject, AdChar,adParamInput, "Some Text"
```

Note that the function includes handling for zero-length parameters (in `Select Case` block) and you may need to change it to be in line with you requirements.

Comment: Thanks for 1) posting an answer to redeem that comment and 2) editing that answer to include some description. (upvoted)