# How to write a value into access database faster - VBA (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to store the values inside an access database from excel using vba.

I have a form in Excel where I get the Inputs from the User.

On VBA, In the Locals window, I could see the values assigned to the object as below,

```
Name = Mike
Age = 23
Occupation = Student
```

On the Access database, I have a table called as `UserTable` which has columns called as `ID, Name, Age, Occupation` and now how do I pass the values from VBA to Access database.

I would want to add the value record by record and faster at the same time.

Here is where I am getting the error

```
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [Name] TEXT(255), [Age] INTEGER, [Occupation] TEXT(255);" _
               & " INSERT INTO UserTable([User Name], [User Age], [User Occupation]);"
```

Please help me with this on my learning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Excel VBA to run SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385245/using-excel-vba-to-run-sql-query)

Comment: @VictorK But my problem is how would you make the record set to copy them into database table.

Comment: You have to look into `ADODB.Connection` and `Insert Into` statement both of which has a plethora of questions here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40127962/8597922),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802120/8597922),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25226635/8597922). As you go you should also check how to use parametrized queries.

Comment: @VictorK Thanks. I followed your links. I am getting an error in the Insert into statement. I have updated the question, Any Idea where it is going wrong ?

Comment: Actually [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46835253/8597922) to a very similar question for `Insert`. And [this is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522802/8597922) that explains parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a reference to the ADO recordset library

create and open a Connection object to the access database

```
 Dim Conn as new adodb.connection
  conn.connectionstring = "google for connection string here"
  conn.open
```

create a string holding an append query (watch out: you need commas between fields and ' around strings)

```
Dim strSQL as string
StrSql = "INSERT INTO [Usertable] ( Name, Age, Occupation ) "
strsql = strsql & "Values('" & me.Name & "'," & me.age & ",'" & me.occupation & "')"
```

Use EXECUTE to run this string

```
conn.execute  strsql
```

Comment: Last time I suggested an unparametrized query here on SO I got [this](https://xkcd.com/327/) as a reply. I guess reasonably so.

Comment: If little bobby tables does that in a work environment he won't be in that environment soon. This is excel and access in an office - not wikileaks's russian database of fake news

Comment: That's not the point. For example a name such as "Sarah O'Connor" which is realistic will not work if either it is not sanitized or parametrized as `'` will blow up the string .